# Pandas: check if a number appear multiple times in a row

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe like below. What I want is that, if a number between columns a,b,c appear most then it should output that number or if the all three numbers are different then take the number of a. For example, in first row, 1 appears most among 1 and 5 then output in d is 1. But in second row, all three numbers 11, 2, 7 of column a,b,c are different, output is the value of column a(11), so output in d is 11

```
list   a  b   c  
 1     1  5   1 
11    11  2   7 
 0     0  0   0 
 9     5  9   5 
 8     8  2   7
```

Expected output

```
list   a  b   c  d 
 1     1  5   1  1
11    11  2   7  11
 0     0  0   0  0
 9     5  9   5  5
 8     8  2   7  8
```

Comment: I’ve never tried it but df.mode(1).iloc[:, 0]

Comment: @piRSquared Wow... had no idea we had a mode function too. (also, it works!)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks for checking (-:

Comment: the iloc doesn't quite work as OP requests though.  mode seems to return sort ordered rather than original order when there is not a strict mode.  e.g. for second row, mode returns [2,7,11] rather than [11,2,7]

Comment: @JohnE that stinks.

Comment: I’ve got an obnoxious bincount argmax solution in mind. If no one else has a good answer in a few hours, I’ll put it together when I get to a place I can code.

Comment: @user1670773, would you like to pick an answer that suits you? There are lots of alternatives so this might help the next person with the same query.

Answer (score 1):

[scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) calculates mode, but I am surprised not to find this in numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 5, 1],
                   [11, 11, 2, 7],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [9, 5, 9, 5],
                   [8, 8, 2, 7]],
                  columns=['list', 'a', 'b', 'c'])

df['d'], df['count'] = stats.mode(df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values, axis=1)
df.loc[df['count'] == 1, 'd'] = df['a']
df = df.drop('count', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `value_counts`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x : x.value_counts().index[0] if x.value_counts().iloc[0]>1 else x['a'] ,1)
Out[1046]: 
0     1
1    11
2     0
3     5
4     8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `bincount` solution

**Data**
Note that this is different from OP's to point out that it works as expected.

```
   list   a  b  c
0     1   5  1  1
1    11  11  2  7
2     0   0  0  0
3     9   5  9  5
4     8   8  2  7
```

---

**Solution**

```
v = df.values[:, 1:]

f, u = pd.factorize([(i, e) for i, row in enumerate(v) for e in row])

counts = np.bincount(f)[f].reshape(v.shape)

x = (counts == counts.max(1, keepdims=1)).argmax(1)
y = np.arange(v.shape[0])

df.assign(d=v[y, x])

   list   a  b  c   d
0     1   5  1  1   1
1    11  11  2  7  11
2     0   0  0  0   0
3     9   5  9  5   5
4     8   8  2  7   8
```

---

**Details**

Get numpy array of just the values we want.

```
v = df.values[:, 1:]
```

Use `enumerate` and comprehension to create a list of tuples.  Each rows values will be distinct from other rows because I'm placing an identifier in the first position of the tuple for each row.  Namely the value from enumerate.  I then pass these into Pandas' `factorize` function in order to place into Numpy's `bincount`.

```
f, u = pd.factorize([(i, e) for i, row in enumerate(v) for e in row])
```

Now I use `bincount` on `f` and slice it with `f` to get an array of the same size, but now filled with count values.

```
counts = np.bincount(f)[f].reshape(v.shape)
```

I locate the maximum values and slice the original array to get what those values where.

```
x = (counts == counts.max(1, keepdims=1)).argmax(1)
y = np.arange(v.shape[0])
```

Note that if all values are the same or if there are multiple modes, `argmax` will pick the first one.  When all are the same, this is column `a`.

```
df.assign(d=v[y, x])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @piRSquared suggested, we can use `mode` function in pandas.

```
df["d"] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique() == 3, 1), 
                   df["a"], 
                   df.mode(1).loc[:,0])
```

Another method (for fun)

```
df["d"] = np.where(df['b'] == df['c'], df['b'], df['a'])
```

Pseudocode explanation

```
if b == c:
    choose b because b and c are both the mode
else:  # when b != c
   if a == c or a == b:
        choose a because a is the mode
   else: # a != b != c
        choose a because all are different
```